# Selectize control misplacement

Tags: javascript, html, css, selectize.js

I have successfully used the selectize.js library before. However in the current scenario I'm experiencing a weird visual bug. As soon as I apply the `selectize` class to my `select` drop down (green box) it gets a weird offset and also the choices which are being displayed are all but tidy too (See red box).

[image: layout-issues]

This is all part of a rails app. And this is my HTML code in slim:

```
.list-group.m-b-md
  .list-group-item
    = simple_form_for new_item, url: idea_interactions_path, remote: true do |f|
      .input-group
        = f.input :sprint_id, as: :hidden
        = f.input :interaction_pairings, label: false, as: :select, collection: interaction_pairings(@sprint), input_html: {class: 'selectize'}
```

And the JS Code which is in Coffee script:

```
#= require selectize

interactionChanged = ->
    alert('Dropdown Changed')

$ ->
  $('.selectize').selectize
    closeAfterSelect: true
    selectOnTab: true
    onChange: interactionChanged
```

Comment: Since the solution involves ancillary CSS outside the scope of the original question, I’m voting to close this question, as it’ll unlikely be of relevance to future readers.

Comment: @JeremyCaney. I see what you're saying. However using selectize.js along with bootstrap to me is not all that exotic. And inside those reals I was not doing anything too fancy.

Comment: Fair enough. And I now see that `form-control` _is_ in the original question—it’s just in the screenshot, not the extracted markup samples. (Though it gibt be generated?) Regardless, I’ve retracted my vote. Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was the CSS class `form-control` removing it solved all of the above issues.